# Sort a dataframe by month and date, but excluding the year

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I am working on a dataFrame with multiple years of data with a timestamp for each value. I am struggling with sorting data for summer/non-summer months. I am not sure how to tell pandas to get the data with dates June 1 to September 30, however discarding the year. I created a psuedo-code of what I want to achieve below, but obviously a timestamp would not work for this case. Thank you for the help, and I apologize for my lack of clarity.

Code is below:
Code is also above as an image:

```
# My goal is to get summer months June 1 to September 30
# I have a multiple years I only want extract the summer months from each year
summer_start = pd.Timestamp(month=6, day=1) # I recognize this will not work without a year. This is pseudo-code
summer_end = pd.Timestamp(month=9, day=30) 
df['Is_Summer'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x >= summer_start && x <= summer_end else 'False')
```

Comment: IF you need exact dates for summer, i would create two columns something like datetime.datetime.date((pd.Timestamp(month=9, day=30, year=2019))).month and .day and check between those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, it is simply month between 6 and 9 inclusive, so you can do

```
 df['is_summer'] = df['Date'].dt.month.between(6,9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one question. What if I wanted to include dates as well? Like for example June 15 to September 15.

Comment: I can not check the mark in 8 minutes, but I will when I can.

Comment: For the other question, do something like month * 100 + day between 615 and 915.